# Create a customer search filter on the woocommerce order page

Tags: woocommerce

How can I create a client search filter on the woocommerce order page?

Example:
Search customer by zip code
Or
Find customer by phone number

To list customer orders

Comment: You mean in backend or front end for customer ? by default woocommerce has this type of search in backed, just type in the key and hit enter.

Comment: Also need this. this "just type" field doesnt search over address, for example

Answer (score 2):

The WooCommerce Order Admin allows you to search for ordres by the following fields:

- order key
- billing first name
- billing last name
- billing company
- billing address 1
- billing city
- billing postcode
- billing country
- billing state
- billing email
- billing phone
- order items

If you need to search by another order field you could add this a functionality plugin or your themes functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total' );
function woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total( $search_fields ) {
    $search_fields[] = '_order_total';
    return $search_fields;
}
```

With that simple snippet active you can now search by order total. Using this technique you can even search by custom post meta that you may be adding to the order records.

credit to [SkyVerge](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/searching-custom-fields-woocommerce-order-admin/) for their docs on this

Comment: How to search by shipping zone?