# Is there a way to filter out "John Smith" orders in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

According to this thread on the Shopify site: https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussions/john-smith-from-google-utm-google-shopper-creating-false/td-p/538519/highlight/false/page/6

Google uses a bot to check if prices on your e-commerce store are the same as what is listed in Google Merchant Center or in ads. It uses a bot by the name of "John Smith" with several IP and email addresses to create 'fake' orders which don't actually go through.

But this is not a Shopify-specific issue, as you'll see when reading through that thread and googling the topic. The Shopify thread just seems to be the most comprehensive talk on the problem.

Also, according to the thread above, trying to block the bot will result in Google not being able to verify what it needs to show your product listings through its system. So a bot blocker won't be ideal.

QUESTION:

I'm wondering if there is a way to just filter these "John Smith" orders so that they go to the trash bin once they're done being abandoned, and so that they are not sent to store owners? One company is getting "failed order" notices every day from "John Smith" WooCommerce and it's very annoying.

This issue also affect statistics like conversion rate and cart abandonment rate. That's another question but if there is a solution to that, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

In WooCommerce orders, you can search orders by customer billing name.

Source: [Create a customer search filter on the woocommerce order page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575100/create-a-customer-search-filter-on-the-woocommerce-order-page)

About Cart abandonment: This is not Woocommerce core functionality, so that you need to check your custom plugin which you are using to find the cart abandonment

Comment: I understand this is possible to do manually. I'm trying to automate the process however. Cart abandonment doesn't refer to a WooCommerce functionality. It refers to how users use the shop. All e-commerce shops can have abandoned carts. This is a tracking metric. If you meant something else, let me know.

Comment: If i understand you correct then you need a function that will trash the order which customer name "John Smith" automatically after order is created. Let me know if I am correct, so i will provide code snippet according to that.

Comment: Yes that is correct